# Django haystack autocomplete ajax (a href wrap into object)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, autocomplete

I'm new to ajax and jQuery and I want to use it in my search with autocomplete. I've followed the official Haystack tutorial for autocomplete ([here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html)) and I can get the results showing correctly. Now I want the shown result to contain the link to the proper page and I don't know how to do it. I have tried to wrap `{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}`, (same as I use when showing search results without autocomplete) into the:

```
 var base_elem = $('<div class="result-wrapper"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}" class="ac-result"></a></div>')
```

but it's not working.

Can somebody please show and explain how should I wrap the url context inside the results? Apparently the key to wrap the link inside my results is not in the Javascript but to construct the URL on the server side and pass it back to the results.

views:

```
def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:10]
    suggestions = [result.username or result.title for result in sqs]
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // In a perfect world, this would be its own library file that got included
    // on the page and only the ``$(document).ready(...)`` below would be present.
    // But this is an example.
    var Autocomplete = function(options) {
      this.form_selector = options.form_selector
      this.url = options.url || '/search/autocomplete/'
      this.delay = parseInt(options.delay || 300)
      this.minimum_length = parseInt(options.minimum_length || 3)
      this.form_elem = null
      this.query_box = null
    }

    Autocomplete.prototype.setup = function() {
      var self = this

      this.form_elem = $(this.form_selector)
      this.query_box = this.form_elem.find('input[name=q]')

      // Watch the input box.
      this.query_box.on('keyup', function() {
        var query = self.query_box.val()

        if(query.length < self.minimum_length) {
          return false
        }

        self.fetch(query)
      })

      // On selecting a result, populate the search field.
      this.form_elem.on('click', '.ac-result', function(ev) {
        self.query_box.val($(this).text())
        $('.ac-results').remove()
        return false
      })
    }

    Autocomplete.prototype.fetch = function(query) {
      var self = this

      $.ajax({
        url: this.url
      , data: {
          'q': query
        }
      , success: function(data) {
          self.show_results(data)
        }
      })
    }

    Autocomplete.prototype.show_results = function(data) {
      // Remove any existing results.
      $('.ac-results').remove()

      var results = data.results || []
      var results_wrapper = $('<div class="ac-results"></div>')
      var base_elem = $('<div class="result-wrapper"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}" class="ac-result"></a></div>')

      if(results.length > 0) {
        for(var res_offset in results) {
          var elem = base_elem.clone()
          // Don't use .html(...) here, as you open yourself to XSS.
          // Really, you should use some form of templating.
          elem.find('.ac-result').text(results[res_offset])
          results_wrapper.append(elem)
        }
      }
      else {
        var elem = base_elem.clone()
        elem.text("No results found.")
        results_wrapper.append(elem)
      }

      this.query_box.after(results_wrapper)
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      window.autocomplete = new Autocomplete({
        form_selector: '.autocomplete-me'
      })
      window.autocomplete.setup()
    })
  </script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no way of parsing django template tags, so in this instance:

```
<a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}" class="ac-result">
```

The `href` will literally be  "`{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}`". What you need to do is construct the URL on the *server side* and pass it back in the `results` data when you call `/search/autocomplete/`.

---

Based on your updated code, you just need to have the server generate a link to your item some how (potentially using [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) for the django object, which has other benefits) and include that in the returned json.

```
def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:10]
    suggestions = [  {'text':result.username or result.title,
                      'url':generate_url(result), }
                    for result in sqs
                  ]
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Then update the loop in `Autocomplete.prototype.show_results` accordingly:

```
  var base_elem = $('<div class="result-wrapper"><a href="" class="ac-result"></a></div>')

  if(results.length > 0) {
    for(var res_offset in results) {
      var elem = base_elem.clone()
      // Don't use .html(...) here, as you open yourself to XSS.
      // Really, you should use some form of templating.
      elem.find('.ac-result').text(results[res_offset].text)
      elem.find('.ac-result').attr("href",results[res_offset].url)

      results_wrapper.append(elem)
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks Lego... any hint on how to do this? my current view code is: def autocomplete(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[:10]
    suggestions = [result.username or result.title for result in sqs]
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')

Comment: Edit that into your question and I can have a look later

Comment: thanks for the help but if I change the code as you suggested the results are not showing in the autocomplete... Can you re-check if all the code is correct?

Comment: The code I can is an indication that should point you in the right direction. As I said, you need to write a way to generate a URL.